# What is the function of different Oracle ASM disk groups?

Tags: oracle

I have three ASM disk groups. **OCR**, **DATA** and **FRA**.

What is the function of **OCR**? I understand **DATA** is where all the database files are kept together with the temp files and redo logs and **FRA** is where archive logs and backups are kept but **OCR** is what I want to know.

Comment: what have you done so far? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. 
 This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
 and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!
 See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1501497)
 See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details

Comment: OCR is most likely where the cluster registry files and voting files are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of disk groups are not pre-determined and have no meaning beyond what the DBA who created them intended. They can be anything, e.g. in my systems we typically have 3 disk groups:

- DATA - data, control and temp files
- REDO - online redo log files
- RECO - recovery area (FRA)

We choose to have a separate REDO disk group so that we can use ultra fast storage for the online redo log files, which has an impact on database performance. The data files can be on less fast storage.

When you install a new ASM system,either Oracle RAC or Restart (stand-alone), the installer will create one disk group where it stores the meta data for the system. Usually this is called DATA, but that is configurable. After the installation completes more disk groups can be added.

As PMDBA already stated, assuming that the names of your disk groups are logically chosen, the OCR disk group would be where the meta data for your cluster is stored. You can check with the asmcmd utility. You would expect at least to see a password file and some ASM entries. This example is from an Oracle Restart system (that has no voting files or OCR):

```
   $ asmcmd
   ASMCMD> ls *

   +DATA/:
   ASM/
   orapwasm
   ...
```